# $.ajax() call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make this call to send data to the server:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/videos"
   data: { title = oembed.title }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I make a call to the Embedly API like so:

```
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
    });
```

so that I have access to the dynamically generated hash `oembed`, and I want to save `oembed.title`. I tried the `$.ajax()` call both outside and within the embedly call, and it seems to prevent the entire call to embedly from working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/videos",
   data: { title: oembed.title }
});
```

Also I don't see any handling of the response. Perhaps you would like to add a `success` handler:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/videos",
       data: { title: oembed.title },
       success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         /* your code here - check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ */
       }
 });
```

Comment: also, should .ajax() be inside or outside the embedly function?

Comment: Most probably yes. Try this $('a.oembed').embedly({ maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ $.ajax( { /*the rest of the arguments */ });
    });

Comment: thanks! this is a noob question but what exactly is a success handler and what does it do?

Comment: The function which you specify is called when a successful response (e.g. HTTP code 200) is returned by the server. The "data" parameter contains the result which the server returned.

Comment: ahh ok, so it's to test if the call went through :)

Comment: Well if you don't need the server's response you can simply ignore it. Apart from "success" there are a few more callbacks available - "error" (raised when an error occurs) and "complete" which is always called no matter if the request was successful or not.

Comment: I actually looked in my database, and the titles are not being inserted into it...

Comment: Ahh, I think it's associated with the `index` method when it should be associated with the `create` method. Each video is added to the database every time I load the index view without the title...

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a comma after:

```
url: "/videos"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `data: { title: oembed.title }` not `=`

Comment: inside or outside the embedly function?

Answer (score 2):

Use a colon instead of a equals, and don't forget the comma after `url`:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/videos",
 data: { title: oembed.title }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line :

```
data: { title = oembed.title }
```

seems not OK ; it should be written this way, so the `data` is a valid JSON object :

```
data: { title : oembed.title }
```

Note : in JSON, the value of an object's property is separed of its name by a colon ; not an equal sign.

See [json.org](http://json.org/) for a reference of the JSON syntax.

Also, you are missing a comma at the end of this line :

```
url: "/videos"
```

which should be written like this :

```
url: "/videos",
```

Comment: should .ajax be inside or outside the embedly function?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you data json declaration to

```
{ "title": oembed.title }
```